# Configuring an iOS 7 application that is compatible with iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, app-store

I have an iOS 6 application that I had created, but not published, at the time when iOS 7 came out and so  I went ahead and updated it to work with iOS 7. And now that I've published the appstore has the following text in the compatibility section for the application:

`Requires iOS 6.1 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPad touch`.

Now my problem is that when trying to install it from the store, onto a device running iOS 6.1, I get prompted to get iOS 7 if I want to continue. Downloading and installing onto a device running iOS 7 works. 
Running on a simulator with iOS 6.1 works perfectly as well.

Has Apple started forcing a os upgrade or have I missed some configuration in Xcode?

Here is what I have (and believe is relevant) in Xcode:

- Valid architectures: `arm64 armv7 armv7s`
- Base SDK: `Lates iOS(iOS 7.0)` // I get no other choice
- iOS Deployment Target `iOS 6.1`

All help would be appreciated in finding out what is going on here.

**UPDATE 1 (25. October):**

I've sent a message through the iTunesConnect portal and gotten a response. I've been asked to point all users having this problem to contact customer support, or contact developer technical support through the appdev portal on Apple's webpage. I've done the latter, and will update when I get a response.

Comment: Where did you set the deployment target? Also, are you using any Cocoapods?

Comment: No CocoaPods, and I set the deployment target under Project >> General >> Deployment info AND verified it under Build Settings >> Deployment. Any other way I might have missed?

Comment: Hmm... no I thought you may have only set it on the project but not the target.

Comment: Ah.. well I guess that would have been too easy ;)

Comment: In Xcode -> Prefs -> Downloads you should be able to download the iOS 6 simulator and SDK. Might be worth a try running in the sim. Will maybe point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to add to my question that I could also run the application in the simulator running iOS 6.1. My mistake. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to a library that is only compiled to iOS 7 that may be the issue ? Although Xcode usually gives you errors for things like that.

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party library, but I'm using the native QuartzCore.